# Set notation & Identities (Proof)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[image: set notation]

The following questions require a true/false statement as well as a supporting claim.

I'm having a hard time understanding set notation as well as their identities. This is my understanding (tentative answers) so far:

1. False, $A\cup B$ intersects $C$ means everything in $A$ and $B$ also happens to be in $C$.
   Then $A$ union ($B$ Intersects $C$) means all elements that are in both $B$ and $C$ in a union with all elements of $A$. However, I cannot put that into a clearer explanation.
2. True, $\setminus$ means set difference. So therefore the union of $A$ and $B$ $- B$ is going to be $A$ because set difference is all elements in $A$ and $B$ that are not in $B$.
3. I'm not even sure how to get started on this. From my understanding this is an axiom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem 1.** You have the right idea, but to correctly disprove a statement, you need a specific counter-example. To illustrate your idea, we could take $A=\{a\}$, $B=\varnothing$, and $C=\{a\}$. Then 
$$
(A\cup B)\cap C=\{a\}\cap\{a\}=\{a\}
$$
while 
$$
A\cup(B\cap C\}=\{a\}\cap\varnothing=\varnothing
$$
This proves that $(A\cup B)\cap C$ is not necessarily the same as $A\cup(B\cap C\}$.

**Problem 2.** I don't think your reasoning is quite sound here. Can you write down an example similar to the one I've provided above to illustrate this claim? Hint: What happens if $A\cap B\neq\varnothing$?

**Problem 3.** This is definitely not an axiom (be **very** careful with what you call an axiom). Again, can you write down a specific example? Hint: Try taking $m=n=1$. Then this is the statement $A_1\subseteq A_1\cap A_2$. Does this make sense?

Comment: Problem 2: A = {1,2,3}, B = {a,b,c}

A ∪ B = {1,2,3,a,b,c}

Comment: Pay attention to my hint!

Comment: Well the hint would mean that there is no intersection between A and B. Therefore when taking the set difference wouldn't it just be A?

Comment: The hint is the opposite of that.

Comment: Oh that's right! That means A = B.

Comment: Not necessarily, but that would certainly work as a counter-example.

Comment: So that means its False, because if A∩B=∅ then the set difference will result in an empty set...right?

Comment: If $A=B$, then $(A\cup B)\setminus B=(A\cup A)\setminus A=A\setminus A=\varnothing$ which is not the same as $A$ (provided $A$ is non-empty of course).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12943/discussion-between-petrov-and-brian-fitzpatrick)