# True or False: $A_i$ Set Theory

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$\displaystyle
\bigcap_{i=1}^nA_i\subseteq \bigcap_{i=1}^{m+n}A_i\
$ and 
$m>0$

I have to describe whether or not this statement is true. From my understanding it is False, but I'm not sure if my logic is flawed.

I took an example where $m=1$ and $n=1$

$\displaystyle
\bigcap_{i=1}^1A_i\subseteq \bigcap_{i=1}^{1+1}A_i\ 
$

$A_1 \subseteq (A_1 \cap A_2)$

So as $m$ increases the intersection would have a smaller probability of being a superset of $\displaystyle \bigcap_{i=1}^nA_i$

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set notation & Identities (Proof)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/670307/set-notation-identities-proof)

Comment: Don't think about *probability* (although your intuition is correct). Try to give a concrete example in which the claim fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are exactly right. Anyway, you should give an example of $A_1$ and $A_2$. You could take $A_1=\{\emptyset\}$, $A_2=\emptyset$.